# Count all connected users on every department

Tags: mysql, join, enums, count

I have this `tellers` which can be considered as `users` on each `service departments`

I have this code which outputs exactly what I want except for the active_tellers field.

```
SELECT service_info.name AS service_name, 
service_info.current_serving AS current_service, 
service_info.last_printed AS last_printed, 
service_info.remaining_queue AS remaining_queue, 
AVG(teller_log.duration), 
service_info.active_tellers AS active_teller 
FROM user_info 
JOIN teller_info 
ON user_info.teller_id = teller_info.teller_id 
JOIN service_info 
ON service_info.service_id = teller_info.service_id 
JOIN teller_log 
ON user_info.user_id = teller_log.user_id 
GROUP BY 
service_info.name
```

It outputs this

[image]

This is my complete database schema

[image]

As you can see in my database schema in my `teller_info table` I have the field `status` and it is `ENUM [Connected, Disconnected]` this is the field that I am trying to get, if `teller_1` is under `Cashier` and it is **`Connected`** it should output `active_teller` in `service_name Cashier` is `1`

The part of code that I'm having a problem is this

```
service_info.active_tellers AS active_teller
```

I've tried

```
(SELECT COUNT(teller_info.teller_id) FROM teller_info WHERE status = "Connected") as a
```

But it outputs incorrect

[image]

**Edit:**

Output of

```
show create table service_info

CREATE TABLE `service_info` (
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_num` int(2) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starting_num` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `ending_num` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `current_serving` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `last_printed` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `remaining_queue` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active_tellers` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Table for service (Cashier, information, repair)'
```

Comment: added the `enums` tag

Comment: can you provide the output of `show create table service_info`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teller_info WHERE teller_info.`status` = "Connected" AND teller_info.service_id = service_info.service_id) AS active_teller
```

Seems to work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try counting the connected tellers within a service

```
SUM(IF(teller_info.status = 'Connected', 1, 0)) AS active_tellers
```

Comment: This seems good, but after I applied it it results to over number. I only have 1 active teller but it says 15.